# Powershell, filters and combining properties

Tags: powershell

I have an AD group that has other AD groups as members.  Some of these groups may have "sub-groups" as well.  I want to recursively descend through this group and find answers to several questions about the users in that group.  For example:

- Is User-X "enabled" in the overall group?
- Does the account of User-X have values in ANY of the properties: AccountExpirationDate, accountExpires and Deleted?

I would like a displayed result that contains the properties: DisplayName, SamAccountName, AccountExpirationDate, accountExpires, Deleted and enabled (from the group object)

I have tried doing an "Add-Member" to insert the "enabled" value from get-ADgroupMember but I get the error:

```
Add-Member : Cannot add a member with the name "enabled" because a member with that name already exists. If you want to over
write the member anyway, use the Force parameter to overwrite it.
```

... but there is no such element as far as I can tell.  I have renamed the member in the Add-Member to several very unique things but I still get the same error.

my current attempt is:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

get-adgroupmember -Identity "My big AD group of groups" -recursive |
    Where-Object -FilterScript {($_.ObjectClass -eq 'user')} |
    ForEach-Object {
        $enabled = $_.enebled
        Get-ADUser `
            -Filter {(name -eq $_.name)} `
            -Properties DisplayName,SamAccountName,AccountExpirationDate,accountExpires,Deleted |
            Add-Member -Name "myITGGroupEnabled" -Value $enabled -MemberType NoteProperty |
            Where-Object `
                -FilterScript {
                    ($_.AccountExpirationDate -lt [datetime]::now) `
                    -OR ($_.accountExpires -eq $true) `
                    -OR ($_.Deleted -eq $true) `
                    -OR ($_.myITGGroupEnabled -eq $false)
                }
            Select-Object DisplayName,SamAccountName,AccountExpirationDate,accountExpires,Deleted,GroupEnabled
        break
    }
```

I am lost.  Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think all you need is a new PSObject. Like this:

```
    ...
    Get-AdUser -Filter {name -eq $_.name} -Properties ....  | % { 
     If  ( ($_.AccountExpirationDate -lt [datetime]::now) `
                    -OR ($_.accountExpires -eq $true) `
                    -OR ($_.Deleted -eq $true) `
                    -OR ($_.myITGGroupEnabled -eq $false)) { 

       New-Object PSObject -Property @{MyITGGRoupEnabled=$enabled}
     }           
    }
```